# iOS App works with Local Device | How Apple store will accept it for iTunes Store

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

I have an application that works with our device that must be installed on local network and then application connects with the device via WIFI.
I am not sure, When I will upload the application to App Store, How Apple would accept the application when they won't be able to test it.

What is the procedure in this way.

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns the policies and procedures of app distribution services, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?(https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ExternalAccessory framework, you will need to be part of the MFi program and as I understand it, you will need to provide Apple with a unit.

If you're talking about a standard service connection over an existing network, you should probably note in the "Notes" section of the submission what part(s) of the app work normally and which parts *require* the external device and note how Apple can get a device unit ***if they need it***.

Comment: Application has 3 main features that only works with the device and I am not using any framework for that. I am connecting with the device with simple Http Request methods to access data from it.

Application's settings option only work without the external device.


I am also not sure, how we can provide apple with the device.

Comment: In this scenario, there's no guaranteed answer from anyone but Apple, but my suggestion is that in addition to the app description itself (which needs to be explicit about the device requirements), clearly describe in the notes section that a device is available if needed for the review and give the contact info for Apple to ask for it.

Comment: Alright! Thanks Brad for your help. I hope Apple will accept our application. :)